# coustom post type query in multi meta_key and meta_value

Tags: wordpress

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('project','department'),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'jurisdiction',
            'value' => $where,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'title',
            'value' => $cat,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'status',
            'value' => $type,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    global $post;
    the_title();
endwhile;
```

Will produce following error

> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../wp-includes/class-wp-meta-query.php on line 584

Comment: Please read a `meta_query` documentation -- https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Please update your question with the value of `$where`, `$cat` and `$type`.

Answer (score 0):

First: In meta_query, do not accept array variable. 
just check this ( $where, $cat and $type ) variable give you right value?

2nd: May be you forget to write relation attribute in your meta_query.

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('project','department'),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
        array(
            'key' => 'jurisdiction',
            'value' => $where,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'title',
            'value' => $cat,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'status',
            'value' => $type,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
```

i hope it'll helpful for you